# sort the table content javascript html only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working a project in which I am making an address book. I am displaying the entered data in the form of a table. [reference image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O58Wb.jpg)I want to sort the data that I am entering through HTML form fields. Below is my code. Any idea how to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
window.onload = function(){

// Buttons
var quickAddBtn = document.getElementById('QuickAdd');
var quickAddFormDiv = document.querySelector('.quickaddForm')
var cancelBtn = document.getElementById('Cancel');
var AddBtn = document.getElementById('Add');
// Form Fields
var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var speaciality = document.getElementById('speaciality');
var practicename = document.getElementById('practicename');
// Divs etc.
var addBookDiv = document.querySelector('.addbook2');
quickAddFormDiv.style.display = "block";

localStorage.clear();
AddBtn.addEventListener("click", addToBook);

addBookDiv.addEventListener("click", removeEntry);

// Storage Array
var addressBook = [];

//localStorage['addbook'] = '[{"lastname":"Sachin B","practicename":"sachin@frameboxx.in","firstname":"93828292","email":"something","speaciality":"Chandigarh"}]';

function jsonStructure(lastname,firstname,email,speaciality,practicename){
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.lastname += ", "+firstname;
    //this.firstname = firstname;
    this.email = email;
    this.speaciality = speaciality;
    this.practicename = practicename;
}

function addToBook(){
    var isNull = lastname.value!='' && firstname.value!='' && email.value!='' && speaciality.value!='' && practicename.value!='';
    if(isNull){
        // format the input into a valid JSON structure
        var obj = new jsonStructure(lastname.value,firstname.value,email.value,speaciality.value,practicename.value);
        console.log(obj);
        addressBook.push(obj);
        localStorage['addbook2'] = JSON.stringify(addressBook);
        console.log(localStorage['addbook2']);
        //quickAddFormDiv.style.display = "none";
        clearForm();
        showaddressBook();
    }
}


function removeEntry(e){
    // Remove an entry from the addressBook
    if(e.target.classList.contains('delbutton')){
        var remID = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');
        addressBook.splice(remID,1);
        localStorage['addbook2'] = JSON.stringify(addressBook);
        showaddressBook();
    }
}

function clearForm(){
    var formFields = document.querySelectorAll('.formFields');
    for(var i in formFields){
        formFields[i].value = '';
    }
}

function showaddressBook(){
    if(localStorage['addbook2'] === undefined){
        localStorage['addbook2'] = '';
    } else {
        addressBook = JSON.parse(localStorage['addbook2']);
        // Loop over the array addressBook and insert into the page
        var str = '<table>'+'<div id="heading">'+'<th>'+'<tr>'+'<td id="hName">Name</td>'+'<td id="hEmail">Email</td>'+
                '<td id="hPracticeName">Practice Name</td>'+
                '<td id="hSpecialty">Specialty</td>'+
                '<td id="hDel"></td>'+'</tr>'+'</div>'+'</th>';
        addBookDiv.innerHTML = '';
        for(var n in addressBook){
             str += '<tr>';
                str += '<td><div class="lastname"><p>' + addressBook[n].lastname + '</p></div></td>';                   
                str += '<td class="email"><p>' + addressBook[n].email + '</p></td>';
                str += '<td class="practicename"><p>' + addressBook[n].practicename + '</p></td>';                  
                str += '<td class="specialty"><p>' + addressBook[n].speaciality + '</p></td>';
                str += '<td class="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="' + n + '">Delete</a></td>';
                str += '</tr>';
            //addBookDiv.innerHTML += str;
            document.getElementsByClassName("addbook2")[0].innerHTML = str;
            console.log(str);
        }
    }
}

showaddressBook();


}
```

Comment: There are already lots of questions like this. I've answered a few already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127125/js-html-how-to-sort-table-with-fixed-subrows/44136347#44136347

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to consider server-side pagination of your data have a look at jquery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/). Demo right [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo).

Simply add jquery as a dependency and initialize the tablesorter plugin on your table like so:

```
// in the <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/tablesorter.js"></script>

// right after calling showaddressBook()
$("table").tablesorter();
```

Comment: how to add that code to my javascript code? as that is in jquery?

Comment: I tried this but still not getting the output. Can you please have a look at my code. I have attached the link to all files . Thanks in advance.index.html = "http://chopapp.com/#rbdllc5l",            addressbook.css = "http://chopapp.com/#rbdllc5l",       addressbook.js="http://chopapp.com/#lv61mafk"

Comment: I am sorry the links you posted are empty at my side.

Comment: can you share your email id? i will send you the files

Comment: https://expirebox.com/download/1d53eac1c090f30c0c30f8a5ed0be7fc.html, https://expirebox.com/download/2954e4389d59a2241ed27657a58ee698.html, https://expirebox.com/download/6ee4129f17df44e2da611de570fbaf3a.html, https://expirebox.com/download/b3258aa7f56ef940458129083787934c.html

Comment: Place the jquery and tablesorter script tag in the header. And you addressbook.js at the very end of the body.

Comment: also do not wait for a $(document).ready() inside your window.onload() function. That callback wont be accessed

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Your html is invalid. No divs inside a table. So  i gues the tablesort wont work in that way.

Comment: but the link you pasted in very comment of yours, that example doesnt have any div inside table.

Comment: Ya but your example has divs, which is WRONG